# Search in global catalog of AD Forest

Tags: c#, windows, server, active-directory, ldap

I need to do LDAP query across all DCs of Forest. I found similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219664/how-to-find-global-catalog-of-active-directory), from which is following code:

```
using (Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
{
    using (GlobalCatalog globalCatalog = currentForest.FindGlobalCatalog())
    {
        using (DirectorySearcher searcher = globalCatalog.GetDirectorySearcher())
        {
            searcher.Filter = "filter to verify existence of user account according to supplied sid";
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
            return (result != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works in my test scenario. Is this the correct way to query information across domains? There are a lot of other posts where they manually enter GC location or search through list of domains. Therefore is there anything I should pay attention to or that could go wrong with this code?

Comment: Using GC is recommended in your case. In multi site environment you need to iterate over global catalogs to ensure that user exists. Be aware that only a part of user attributes is stored in GC. ObjectSid attribute exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Domains` property of `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest`  to iterate through the domains and then the `DomainControllers` property of `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain` to iterate though domain controllers, running whatever query you want on each.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using global catalogue? It seems to be more effective, since there should always be one and contain a copy of data from all DCs.

Comment: @Geralt No, but you said you needed to query all domain controllers. If you only need to query each domain, you can use the GC if you want, but bear in mind that you can have more than one GC and some information in AD isn't replicated and is therefore different on each DC. Account login times and lockouts for example.

Comment: I see. I need to verify existence of users based on their sid from elsewhere. I was hoping and wanted to verify that this information is available in GC and replicated from all domains there. And if there are more GCs I was led to believe they should hold copies of the same information.

Comment: You can check if users exist on any DC, but if you are creating users as well as checking, you will need to account for replication times.